# Bamboo randomly runs different version of msbuild.exe and build fails

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, bamboo, sql-server-data-tools

I use Bamboo to build my SSDT database solution using VS2012. The problem began when I added database unit test project to the solution. It is random that sometimes build fails with message:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist
> in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Bamboo always runs msbuilds from this location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

I noticed that **whenever build fails** the msbuild.exe output is this:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.18408
>
> [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18449]

but **when build succeed** then output is this:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.34209
>
> [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34209]

I don't know where is it taking version 4.0.30319.18408 from. I searched whole disk for msbuild.exe and executed everyone and none of them has version 4.0.30319.18408.

I need an advice how to force Bamboo to run correct version of msbuild.exe or how to uninstall version 4.0.30319.18408.

Components on the build machine are following:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack                        4.0.30319  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack                      4.5.50709  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK                                       4.5.50710  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack                    4.5.51651  
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)              4.5.51209  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) - ENU                  10.0.40219  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU                    10.0.40219  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Devenv                                    11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Devenv Resources                          11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Performance Collection Tools              11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Performance Collection Tools - ENU        11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Preparation                               11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Minimum)                           11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Minimum) Interop Assemblies        11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Minimum) Resources                 11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 ENU  4.0.8876.1  
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012                              11.0.50727  
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 - ENU                        11.0.50727  
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools – Database Projects – Web installer... 10.3.20116.0  
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu (11.1.50318.0)                   11.1.50318.0  
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Build Utilities - enu (11.1.40403.0)   11.1.40403.0
```

There is no msbuild in the PATH.

EDIT:
Components list is scripted with PowerShell. I just noticed that actual list in Programs and Features is shorter. There is only one Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Comment: Isn't perhaps the problem that some of your bamboo agents have Visual Studio installed, while the others don't?

Comment: This build plan always run on one dedicated machine.

Answer (score 0):

I modified Bamboo task not to call msbuild executable but to run such script:

```bsh
    ECHO Setting variables
    CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

    ECHO Starting msbuild.exe
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe .\SVN_CHECKOUT\Databases\Databases.sln /fileLoggerParameters:LogFile=".\msbuild.log.txt" /p:Configuration=Release /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly;Verbosity=quiet;Summary /m
```

So far it works.